# Why do entered input values disappear when additional inputs are added with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a simple form with two input fields. One for a product name
and another one for a price. When I enter a product name as well
as a product price and click on a button that adds 1 more field
for another product and a price, another product field and price field
are added but the entered input values becoming deleted...

How can I keep the entered values in the input fields without being cleared?

This is my JavaScript code:

```
<script>
var total_products = 1;
function add_fields() {
    var d = document.getElementById("products_services");
    total_products++;
    d.innerHTML += "<div class=\"form-group\"><label for=\"product"+total_products+"\" class=\"col-sm-4 control-label\">Product "+total_products+"</label><div class=\"col-sm-6\"><input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"product"+total_products+"\" placeholder=\"Product "+total_products+"\"></div></div>";
    d.innerHTML += "<div class=\"form-group\"><label for=\"price"+total_products+"\" class=\"col-sm-4 control-label\">Price "+total_products+"</label><div class=\"col-sm-6\"><input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"price"+total_products+"\" placeholder=\"Price "+total_products+" (e.g. 479.59)\"></div></div>";
}
</script>
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="index.php" method="post">
<div id="products_services">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="product1" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Product 1</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="product1" placeholder="Product 1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="price1" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Price 1</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="price1" placeholder="Price 1 (e.g. 479.59)">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-6">
  <button type="button" onclick="add_fields()" class="btn btn-default">Add 1 more Product</button> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: you are causing the dom to be rewritten by assigning to `innerHTML`

Comment: Is there a way to keep the entered values with raw JavaScript (no framework like jQuery)?

Comment: use `element.appendChild`.

Comment: Here -> http://jsfiddle.net/ch3w6r15/

Comment: @adeneo This works well and is exactly what I searched for. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

When you add extra HTML to the `products_services` div you are causing it to recreate every element it contains from scratch, hence the inputs are blank.

A better way to extend the contents of an element is to call `document.createElement`to create a new elements.

Try this change to your code:

```
var D = document.getElementById("products_services");
var d=document.createElement('div');
D.appendChild(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant set it like that, using just `innerHTML`. You need to append the new forms. 
Take a look at the following code.

```js
var total_products = 1;

window.add_fields = function() {
  total_products++;
  var d = document.getElementById("products_services");

  var htmlObject = document.createElement('div');
  var textnode = "<div class=\"form-group\"><label for=\"product" + total_products + "\" class=\"col-sm-4 control-label\">Product " + total_products + "</label><div class=\"col-sm-6\"><input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"product" + total_products + "\" placeholder=\"Product " + total_products + "\"></div></div>";
  textnode += "<div class=\"form-group\"><label for=\"price" + total_products + "\" class=\"col-sm-4 control-label\">Price " + total_products + "</label><div class=\"col-sm-6\"><input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" name=\"price" + total_products + "\" placeholder=\"Price " + total_products + " (e.g. 479.59)\"></div></div>";

  htmlObject.innerHTML = textnode;
  d.appendChild(htmlObject);


}
```

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" action="index.php" method="post">
  <div id="products_services">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="product1" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Product 1</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="product1" placeholder="Product 1">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="price1" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Price 1</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="price1" placeholder="Price 1 (e.g. 479.59)">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-6">
      <button type="button" onclick="add_fields()" class="btn btn-default">Add 1 more Product</button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using something like this rather than adding raw HTML:

```js
$("<input type='text' value='' />")
     .attr("id", "myfieldid")
     .attr("name", "myfieldid")
     .appendTo("#TheFormYouAddTo");
```

Youll have to give your form an id and place that inside of the .appendTo("#ID"); but this should not update all of the html.

Comment: There's no jQuery tag, do you have a plain JS version of that as well ?

Comment: Ahh you are correct, my fault.